# How to find the top level hierarchy of one column from another column in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to find the top level hierarchy of an employee in an organization and assign the reporting levels using pyspark?

We have already used spark GraphX to solve this issue with Scala support. We would like to do this in python but not using Graphframes (DFs first preference). is it possible to do it using spark DFs? If not, then we will go for Graphframes.

There are 2 DFs i.e., employee_df and required_hierarchy_df

1. employee_df contains all the information of all the employees in an organization.
2. required_hierarchy_df contains the employees' for whom we need to find his/her top hierarchy in an organization.

Please refer to below example:

required_hierarchy_df:

```
employee_id | designation | supervisor_id | supervisor_designation
10          | Developer   | 05            | Techincal Lead
```

employee_df :

```
employee_id  | designation | supervisor_id  | supervisor_designation
10           | Developer   | 05             | Techincal Lead
05           | Technical Lead | 04          | Manager
04           | Director    | 03             | Sr. Director
03           | Sr. Director| 02             | Chairman
02           | Chairman    | 01             | CEO
01           | CEO         | null           | null
```

Expected Outputs :

Reporting Levels of an employee :

report_level_df :

```
employee_id | level_1_id | level_2_id | level_3_id | level_4_id | level_5_id
10          | 05         | 04         | 03         | 02         | 01
```

Top Hierarchy information in an organization :

top_level_df :

```
employee_id | designation | top_level_id | top_level_designation
10          | Developer   | 01           | CEO
```

Comment: You only need `employee_df` to accomplish this right? For every `employee_id` find the "highest" (lowest number) chained supervisor there is?

Comment: how many rows are there (potentially) in `employee_df`?

Comment: Hi @LaurensKoppenol .. Sorry for replying late. 
1) Yes, We only need `employee_df` to accomplish this. Right it's like chained hierarchy. 
First to find the matching **employee_ids** between `required_hierarchy_df` and `employee_df` --> Second, is to keep searching the **supervisor_ids** untill it doesn't have a 'null' (means he is the top person in that organization for an employee).

So, in my example for employee_id = 10 (Developer) , the top person in that organization is employee_id = 01 (CEO).

Comment: There are like approx two millions records in the employee_df file, But if the logic is there, I will look for the performance issues or challenges later. But right now we don't have any logic to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

Consider not using spark as its only 2 million rows. Using a dict-/graph-/tree-like datastructure makes this very simple. I would recommend **not** to do this using Spark DataFrames.

Using Spark DataFrames you could solve this by a recursive join, creating the dataframe `report_level_df`. This is not a nice and/or efficient solution

### Code

We are interested in employee - supervisor relationships.

```
edges = employee_df.select('employee_id', 'supervisor_id')
```

Taking a single step up the ladder, so to speak, requires a single join

```
level_0 = edges \
  .withColumnRenamed('employee_id', 'level_0') \
  .withColumnRenamed('supervisor_id', 'level_1')

level_1 = edges \
  .withColumnRenamed('employee_id', 'level_1') \
  .withColumnRenamed('supervisor_id', 'level_2')

# Join, sort columns and show
level_0 \
  .join(level_1, on='level_1') \
  .select('level_0', 'level_1', 'level_2') \
  .show()
```

And we want to traverse them up the chain, recursively.

```
total = edges \
  .withColumnRenamed('employee_id', 'level_0') \
  .withColumnRenamed('supervisor_id', 'level_1')

levels = 10

for i in range(1, levels):
  level_i = edges \
    .withColumnRenamed('employee_id', 'level_{}'.format(i)) \
    .withColumnRenamed('supervisor_id', 'level_{}'.format(i+1))

  total = total \
    .join(level_i, on='level_{}'.format(i), how='left')

# Sort columns and show
total \
  .select(['level_{}'.format(i) for i in range(levels)]) \
  .show()
```

Except that we don't want to guess the number of levels, so we check every time if we are done yet. This requires a run over all data, and is therefore slow.

```
schema = 'employee_id int, supervisor_id int'
edges = spark.createDataFrame([[10, 5], [5, 4], [4, 3], [3, 2], [2, 1], [1, None]], schema=schema)

total = edges \
  .withColumnRenamed('employee_id', 'level_0') \
  .withColumnRenamed('supervisor_id', 'level_1')

i = 1

while True:
  this_level = 'level_{}'.format(i)
  next_level = 'level_{}'.format(i+1)
  level_i = edges \
    .withColumnRenamed('employee_id', this_level) \
    .withColumnRenamed('supervisor_id', next_level)

  total = total \
    .join(level_i, on=this_level, how='left')

  if total.where(f.col(next_level).isNotNull()).count() == 0:
    break
  else:
    i += 1

# Sort columns and show
total \
  .select(['level_{}'.format(i) for i in range(i+2)]) \
  .show()
```

**Result**

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|level_5|level_4|level_3|level_2|level_1|level_0|level_6|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   null|   null|   null|   null|   null|      1|   null|
|   null|   null|   null|   null|      1|      2|   null|
|   null|   null|   null|      1|      2|      3|   null|
|   null|   null|      1|      2|      3|      4|   null|
|   null|      1|      2|      3|      4|      5|   null|
|      1|      2|      3|      4|      5|     10|   null|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Solution @Laurens Koppenol. This works well for me :-)